# Why is Angular Error handle not throwing error from service

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have implemented a method to handle errors when anything goes wrong in my service call to the api.
In the code I pass the reference to my error handler to the Rxjs catchError operator as below:

```
GetUserByUserID(id: number): Observable<UserDetails> {
  const url = `${this.baseUrl}/${this.userByID}/${id}`;

  return this.http.get<UserDetails>(url, this.httpOptions)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

ErrorHandler:

```
import { Observable, throwError as observableThrowError } from 'rxjs';

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  console.log(error);
  if (error.status === 400) {
    return observableThrowError(new BadRequestError(error.error));
  }

  if (error.status === 404) {
    return observableThrowError(new NotFoundError());
  }

  if (error.status === 401) {
    return observableThrowError(new UnAuthorizedError(error));
  }

  if (error.status === 403) {
    return observableThrowError(new ForbiddenError(error));
  }

  return observableThrowError(new AppError(error));
}
```

In this error handler method I return an Observable that includes an error that is specific to my application domain (Error Domain), I have created different error classes so I just check that the error is an instance of one of my error domain classes when I subscribe to the Observable.

```
this.router.data
  .subscribe(response => {
    this.UserDetail = response.userDetail;
    console.log(this.UserDetail);
  }, (error: AppError) => {
    if (error instanceof BadRequestError) {
      this.notifierService.notify('error', 'lease Register to login');
    } else {
      this.notifierService.notify('error', 'Something went worng... Please try again in few minutes');
    }
  }
});
```

Having all these in place to handle the error, i.e return an Observable of error specific to my application and finally check it's an instance of one of my error domain when subscribed to doesn't actually seems to be working, I keep getting this error in the console:

[image]

Comment: What's the expected behaviour?

Comment: @CristianTraìna The expected behaviour is that it should rethrow an observable of one of the error models specific to my application, so that when I subscribe to the observable i can just check for the instance and show a specific message based on this error model. In these error models I just log and do stuff with the actual error.